# Django asking for a default link to parent model for inherited model

Tags: python, django

I have made some models in my Django app to describe different types of polls that exist in my application.

```
from django.db import models
from api.models.helpers import JSONSerializableModel
from api.models.speaker import Speaker
from api.models.auth import Attendee
from api.models.event import Event



class BasePoll(JSONSerializableModel, models.Model):

    text = models.CharField('text', max_length=300, blank=False)



class MultipleChoicePoll(JSONSerializableModel, models.Model):

    @property
    def results(self):
        results = multiplechoicepollresponse_set.all().annotate(Count('multiplechoicepollresponse'))
        return average_rating


class RatingPoll(BasePoll):
    @property
    def average(self):
        average_rating = ratingpollresponse_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))
        print(average_rating)
        return average_rating


class OpenQuestionPoll(BasePoll): 
    pass
```

I've made the migration and all seemed fine, but now when I try to use the interactive shell:

```
In [6]: poll = MultipleChoicePoll.objects.all()[0]

In [7]: poll.text = 'Some poll text'

In [8]: poll.save()

In [9]: poll = MultipleChoicePoll.objects.all()[0]

In [10]: poll.text
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-28f6dbcd48ba> in <module>()
----> 1 poll.text

AttributeError: 'MultipleChoicePoll' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Now, when I inherit from BasePoll, what happens each child model gets an automatic basepoll_ptr One2One field. But when I migrate, it asks fro a default on this field, which is not possible, as this field is created by Django, and not me:

```
    You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'basepoll_ptr' to multiplechoicepoll without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

Comment: In your code snippet MultipleChoicePoll is not inherited from BasePoll.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Ah, it's just a stupid typo. I thought I was missing something more general.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner however, now it asks me for a default value for the `basepoll_ptr` when I migrate. But how can there be a default for that?

Comment: What is basepoll_ptr? Can you post related code?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner What I tried to do, was remove  `abstract = True ` from BasePoll, so now  BasePoll is a real model. Now, when I inherit from  BasePoll, what happens each child model gets an automatic `basepoll_ptr` One2One field. But when I migrate, it asks fro a default on this field, which is not possible, as this field is created by Django, and not me.